# Django filter by latest date in python

Tags: python, django, filter, model, django-queryset

I have the following model

```
class CoinsQuotes(models.Model):
    coinQuotesID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    coinID = models.ForeignKey(Coins, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coinCurrency= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    coinPrice =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8, max_digits=40)
    coinVolume24h = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=30)
    coinPercentageChange1h =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange24h =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange7D =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange30D =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange60D =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange90D =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinPercentageChange180D =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinMarketCap =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinQuoteLastUpdated =  models.DateTimeField('quoteLastUpdated')
    coinQuotesSnapDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)

class CoinsPortfolio(models.Model):
    coinPortfolioID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    coinID = models.ForeignKey(Coins, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coinName= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    coinUSDNotional=  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=30)
    coinAmount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=10, max_digits=30)
    coinBookPrice =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=10, max_digits=40)
    coinMarketPrice =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=10, max_digits=40)
    coinBookFees =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    coinBookDate = models.DateTimeField('coinBookDate')
    coinQuoteLastUpdated =  models.DateTimeField('quoteLastUpdated')
    coinQuotesSnapDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
```

and I am using the current view to extract the latest quotes for all coins.

```
     latest_date = CoinsQuotes.objects.aggregate(latest1 = Max('coinQuotesSnapDate')).['latest1']
    pct_chg = CoinsQuotes.objects.all().filter(coinQuotesSnapDate = latest_date)
```

for a reason it's returning only one item, while in fact there are 10 coins with the latest time?
additionally is there a way to filter within a template of or alternatively should I link those 2 models with many to many relationship?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you share what type and value `latest_date` has? And also show the dates of the 10 objects that match this filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest **CoinsQuotes** by this adding `-order_by` :-

```
latest_date = CoinsQuotes.objects.all().order_by('-coinQuotesSnapDate')
```

[order_by - Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

> You don't need extra code for this, So you can remove above code.

**EDIT :-**

It will get only `10` posts of today (You can also retrieve from different date)

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
latest_date = CoinsQuotes.objects.filter(coinQuotesSnapDate__gt = today).order_by('-coinQuotesSnapDate')[:10]
```

Comment: I think the actual date is ```coinQuotesSnapDate```. That's what the OP is using in his query.

Comment: Yes! , Right. Updated the Answer

Comment: well the problem is that i want to retrieve one latest date and based on that latest date I want to extract all entries. so yes Iam coinQuotesSnapDate, so i need to filter somehow but the filter is returning only on object, while there are at least 10 entries matching this date

Comment: @CamilleBeyrouthy, So you mean if today  is `1 January` then show 10 posts of 1 january only.

Comment: Hi  @PrOgRaMmEr , I mean on the latest date and time, e.g. Aug. 7, 2021, 2:09 p.m.

Comment: there is 10 entries in the database, I want to be able to extract those.

Comment: my original code is rerturning only one entry, dont know why the filter is not including all entries respective to the coinQuotesDate, e.g.Aug. 7, 2021, 2:09 p.m.